# Why does StackOverflowError occur in the below scenario?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}

public class A {

    A b = new A();
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't? What does initializing an `A` instance do?

Comment: It creates a new object 'a' in the heap memory and then an object 'b'. I am not able to understand why these causes a stack overflow

Comment: its simple... everytime you create an instance of A you recursively create b and thus its going on a infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every `A` creates an inner field named `b` of type `A`. That's infinitely recurisve, because to create a `b` you must also create an `A` (which adds another `b`). Because initializers are copied to the default constructor, your example is equivalent to something like,

```
public class A {
   // A b=new A(); 
   A b;
   public A() {
       super();
       b = new A();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Elliott Frisch for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your requirement. Why did you declare instance variable within same class. It will behave like a recursive loop. From the main method it will try to create the object of class A and during that object creation it will try to initialize the variable "a". As a result again it will create another instance of A and so on.